# Cookie not getting deleted

Tags: javascript, vb.net, cookies

In my asp.net application, am creating a cookie from server side using following code

```
 Dim aCookie As New HttpCookie("StartDownload")
 aCookie.Value = "True"
 aCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1)
 Response.Cookies.Add(aCookie)
```

When I execute this code, the cookie is getting created,  but am not able to delete the cookie from javascript on click of a button.  Below is the javascript code.

```
function delCookie() {
    alert(document.cookie);
    document.cookie = "StartDownload" + "=; expires=" + new Date(0).toUTCString();
    alert(document.cookie);
}
```

Am using IE browser.  Not sure what the problem is.  Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to hardcode the expiry date, something like, `Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT` and see if that'd work for you or not.

If still not, you might want to ask yourself following questions:

- Have you checked the client-side and server-side cookie domains and paths to ensure they're the same?
- Is one cookie secure and the other not?
- Are there any server/client clock sync issues?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how do i check this "Have you checked the client-side and server-side cookie domains and paths to ensure they're the same?"

Comment: You can check your cookie domain and path in your web browser, e.g. in Chrome, Settings->Show advanced settings->Privacy,Content settings->All cookies and site data->find your cookie and click its icon to see details.

Comment: You also might want to assign values to `aCookie.Path` & `aCookie.Domain` just to see if it'd make any differences on your client side.

Comment: I had the same problem of mismatch of domain & path! I hard coded them (to match with the original cookie) along with the date (past date to delete the cookie). It worked!! Thanks a lot @woodykiddy